# Rails 5.1: Why doesn't my submit button become disabled when the form is being submitted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form which contains a file field. If the user adds a file, the form will take a few moments to submit. As such, I want to disable the submit button while the form is submitting.

My form looks like this:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@user, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, required: true, autocomplete: "name" %>
  <%= f.date_select :date_of_birth,
                    required: true,
                    include_blank: true,
                    start_year: Time.current.year - 90,
                    end_year: Time.current.year - 17
  %>

  <%= f.file_field :cv, label: "Your CV", accept:"application/pdf, 
    application/zip,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", placeholder: "Choose a PDF or DOC file" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :cv_cache, id: "cv_cache" %>

  <%= f.submit "Submit application", id: "application_submit_button", data: { disable_with: "Submitting..." } %>
<% end %>
```

I have `jquery` and `ujs` in my pipeline:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap

//= require_tree .
```

I have used the `data: { disable_with: "Submitting..." }` option on my submit button. My expectation is that when the user clicks submit, the button is disabled and it's text becomes 'Submitting'. That doesn't happen. Whilst the for is submitting, the button remains active and its text is unchanged.

Is there anything that I might have missed? Am I incorrect in assuming that `data: { disable_with: "Submitting..." }` disables the button whilst the form is being submitted? What further steps do I need to take to ensure the button disables?

**Update:**

As mentioned in the reply to the answer below, I have also tried the following without any luck:

```
<%= f.submit "Submit application", id: "application_submit_button", disable_with: "Submitting..." %>
```

**Update 2:**

`disable_with: "Submitting..."` does not generate the correct tag. It generates `data_disable_with` not `data-disable-with`:

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit application" id="application_submit_button" data_disable_with="Submitting..." class="btn btn-secondary" data-disable-with="Submit application">
```

`data_disable_with="Submitting..."` vs `data-disable-with="Submit application"`

The correct tag *is* generated when I use: `data: { disable_with: "Submitting..." }`

I have confirmed that the JS tags are loaded in the header.

My generated tag is:

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Submit application" id="application_submit_button" data-disable-with="Submitting..." class="btn btn-secondary">
```

I still have no idea why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

There is no errors in your code and it should work as expected.

> Whilst the for is submitting, the button remains active

It seems to me that some js scripts aren't loaded. Can you ensure (by using Developers Tools or by "View page source" in your browser) that the page `head` tag includes all the scripts you mentioned from `application.js`

```js
<script src="/assets/rails-ujs.self-xxxxx.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/activestorage.self-xxxxx.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-xxxxx.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery3.self-xxxxx.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/popper.self-xxxxx.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.self-xxxxx.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.self-xxxxx.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
```

Do you use some script blocker extensions in your browser?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that all the tags are in the header. However, I noticed that the generated submit tag contains two `data-disable-with` attributes. I've updated my question to mention this.

Comment: Actually, that's not quite true. One is `data-disable-with` the other is `data_disable_with`.

Comment: Maybe there are some errors while scripts executing in browser? Browser console shows nothing? Can you temporarily omit all the form fields, leaving just submit button?

Answer (score 0):

`disable_with` is an option you specify directly on the submit button, not through the `data` attribute:

```
<%= f.submit "Submit application", id: "application_submit_button", disable_with: "Saving..." %>
```

Comment: This way doesn't generated the correct tag. See my updates.